# When i resize my gnome-terminal with installed oh-my-zsh and powerlevel9k theme i can see problem with redrawing

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, gnome-terminal

I got problem with gnome-terminal with oh-my-zsh and powerlevel9k theme. When i resize terminal during redrawing my line really messing up. I will show you screen from my desktop to check problem. 
I've searched how resolve this problem but i didn't find how fix this issue. Anybody can help me?
[screen with issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKzuQ.png)

I use pop-os 19.04 with gnome-terminal version 3.32.1.
If anybody can help i will be really grateful!

Answer (score 2):

That's how zsh does it. You could call it a bug. I have a fix in https://github.com/romkatv/zsh/tree/fix-winchanged if this bothers you. My [attempt to upstream this patch](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers//2019/msg00561.html) was met with negative feedback and no enthusiasm. Unfortunately, the criticism was too vague to allow me to respond to it and I wasn't able to get any additional details after asking for clarification. I decided to abandon this patch even though it works.

See [this powerlevel10k issue](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/issues/175) for details.

Answer (score 1):

This is a terminal thing, not a bug of Powerlevel9k or any other prompt themes.

> So, unfortunately, this really isn't something P9k can fix. This is due to how your terminal emulator is triggering re-draws of the prompt, and different emulators handle it differently. This is why you don't see this problem on iTerm2 when you resize in one direction, but it does appear when you do it twice, etc.,
>
> Sorry, all, but this is a terminal thing, not a P9k thing! :(

In my test on macOS, this duplicate redrawing doesn't appear in iTerm2, kitty, alacritty.

References

- [Powerlevel9k/powerlevel9k issue#881](https://github.com/Powerlevel9k/powerlevel9k/issues/881)
- [Powerlevel9k/powerlevel9k issue#992](https://github.com/Powerlevel9k/powerlevel9k/issues/992)